# SyntaxError: missing ; before statement in JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, rest

I am getting a very strange error while the response is correct and I can see the JSON content:

here is the request:

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: urlTwitter,
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    async: false,
                    success: function (resp, status, xhr) {
                       $("#message").html("STATUS: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText + "\n" + resp);
                       $("#message").hide();
                       $.each(resp, function() {
                            $.each(this, function(i, tweet) {
                                arrayTweets.push(tweet);
                            });

                        });

                        displayTweets();
                    },
                    error: function(resp, status, xhr){
                        $("#message").html("ERROR: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText + "\n" + resp.e);
                        $("#message").show();
                    }
                });
```

Here is the conent in the response:

```
{"tweet":[{"text":"RT @OSCARHAROTASEND: MUYYY CONTENTO Y MUYYY ORGULLOSO del trabajo d mi hermanito @pablonieto22 en la presentaciÃ³n d su TEAM @CalvoTeam anocâ€¦","user":"Jemurillove"}]}
```

Anyone has a clue, I've been fighting with this half day.

Appreciate any help.

Thanks,

**EDIT:**

this is my resource, if it can help. And the Tweet object is annotated with `@XmlRootElement`:

```
@GET
    @XmlElement(name = "tweet")
    @Path("/retrieveTweets")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<Tweet> retrieve(@QueryParam("lat") Double Latitude, @QueryParam("lon") Double Longitude, @QueryParam("rad") Double Radius, @QueryParam("from") String From, @QueryParam("to") String To) {
        //List<Status> tweets = null;
        List<Tweet> lTweets = new ArrayList<Tweet>();
        boolean status = false;

        Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();

        AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken(TwitterInterface.ACCESS_TOKEN, TwitterInterface.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);
        twitter.setOAuthConsumer(TwitterInterface.CONSUMER_KEY, TwitterInterface.CONSUMER_SECRET);
        twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(accessToken);

        try {
            Query query = new Query("");
            GeoLocation geo =  new GeoLocation(Latitude, Longitude);
            query.setGeoCode(geo, Radius/1000, Query.KILOMETERS);
            query.setCount(100);
            query.setSince(From);
            query.setUntil(To);
            QueryResult result;
            result = twitter.search(query);
            List<Status>tweets = result.getTweets();
            for (Status tweet : tweets) {
                System.out.println("@" + tweet.getUser().getScreenName() + " - " + tweet.getText() + " - " + tweet.getCreatedAt());
                Tweet t = new Tweet();
                t.setUser(tweet.getUser().getScreenName());
                t.setText(tweet.getText());
                lTweets.add(t);
            }
        }
        catch (TwitterException te) {
            te.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Failed to search tweets: " + te.getMessage());
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        return lTweets;
```

Comment: are you using `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />` in your page?

Comment: @anurupr no I am not.

Comment: Response you posted clearly means, that request does not runs as JSONP, because we don't see data wrapped in callback. I see you assigned async: false, but JSONP request cannot be synchronous. Try to remove this line and check response. It should be like `callback323123123123({ /* data here */ })`

Comment: After edit I see you use your own proxy, not direct twitter API call. In this case you need to make JSONP-compatible response. See @knolleary answer.

Comment: @Tommi removing async gives the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are requesting a `jsonp` response, but the response is plain JSON.

You can either change the request type to 'JSON' - if the request doesn't fall foul of cross-domain restrictions, or change whatever is generating the response to wrap the response as JSONP.

For more information on JSONP, have a look at the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/#jsonp)

In summary, jQuery automatically adds a `callback=?` parameter to the url it requests. Your server-side code needs to use the value of that parameter as the name of a javascript function your response should invoke with the JSON passed as an argument.

For example, if `callback=helloWorld`, your response should be:

```
helloWorld({"tweet": ... });
```

Comment: I checked that thanks, but I don't really see in it how can I wrap my JSON in JSONP?

Comment: I've edited my qquestion as well and showed you the resource.

Comment: At which point the question is no longer about JSON/JavaScript, but how to generate JSONP from your annotated Java server side response ... which I can't help you with.

Comment: Given we've 'solved' the original question, consider accepting an answer for other's who search for this error message.

Comment: I don't familar with Java, but [this](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2013/04/moxy-and-json-with-padding.html) looks easy.

Comment: @knolleary It actually hots the error function and not success: with status 200 ok and I can see the whole json responce (correct) but statusText of the error is "parserror" infact.

Here is the resp: Object { readyState=4, status=200, statusText="parsererror", more...}

Comment: @knolleary, seems that the function to add you were telling me about is the solution...I added jsoncallback to the URL, but Im missing a piece: if I put it jsoncallback=fnName, where should I declare or have this function (server side or client side and where)?

Comment: Solved! I was running it from a simple HTML file...so I created a client web app with this file. There was no need for JSONP even.

Comment: I need answer for plain html.. what should i do @Magini